# Does this experiment put an end to Copenhagen (and all epistolar) interpretations of QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, quantum-interpretations, neutrons

The article from April 2022 in PhysRev Research is about the famous double slit experiment (Mach Zehnder variant) made with single neutrons and it proves that there is definitely something in both channels. Namely they calculated that 1/3 of the neutron goes physically through path 1 and 2/3 goes physically through path 2 of the Mach Zehnder.

As I understand Bohr and Born interpretation insists that as the neutron is indivisible (in low energy interactions) the neutron should go through only one path and the wave function goes through both. Wave function is amplitude of the possibility e.g. epistolar (has no physical reality) and there should be an empty wave through one of the slits. Lemmel et al. prove that this is wrong. What do you think?

The article is here:

Quantifying the presence of a neutron in the paths of an interferometer

Hartmut Lemmel, Niels Geerits, Armin Danner, Holger F. Hofmann, and Stephan Sponar
Phys. Rev. Research 4, 023075 – Published 27 April 2022,

DOI: [10.1103/PhysRevResearch.4.023075](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevResearch.4.023075)

Also on arxiv: [2202.00272] [Quantifying the presence of a neutron in the paths of an interferometer](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.00272)

Answer (score 0):

No, this experiment doesn’t destroy any major interpretation of quantum mechanics. What’s new here isn’t that the neutron’s wavefunction is present in both paths — that has been known for decades. The new feature here seems to be that the probabilities for taking each path are unequal.

The Copenhagen interpretation says that you’ll only get one neutron at a time interacting with the *detector system*, which is still the case here. As the authors write,

> In neutron interferometry we always have clear experimental evidence that the interference is based on self-interference of individual particles. Firstly, neutrons are fermions and would never occupy the same state, and secondly the beam intensity is so low that there are virtually never two particles simultaneously in the setup. Still, the visibility of interference itself requires a whole ensemble of neutrons, allowing alternative interpretations of quantum mechanics which assume locality of single particles. The present experiment rules out such statistical interpretations due to the vanishing error of the path presence determined by the weak values.
>
> […]
>
> It should be emphasized that all of these results are completely consistent with standard quantum theory. The conclusion that particles can be physically delocalized between paths in which no strong interactions occur and that the localization or delocalization is decided by a measurement that takes place after the particles have propagated along the paths is a possibility inherent in the paradoxical aspects of quantum superpositions. What is new in the present work is that we demonstrate that standard quantum theory predicts precise and specific effects of the presence of a particle in a path, even when the particle only undergoes a very weak interaction on its way though the interferometer.

I think this says that, in a “alternative interpretation” where a “real neutron” only goes through one path or the other, the feedback compensation provided via their weak-measurement approach would have produced a different statistical distribution than they have observed here.

Comment: The presence of WF in both paths is not new here or was ever. The authors insist that part of the particle (not probability) is in each channel. This is closer to Schoedinger interpretation of WF as density. Any experiment so far found the particle in just one path.

Comment: The wave function is only "present" for the ensemble of neutrons. That does not change in this experiment. Neither does it change the observation that in single instances a quantum field does not behave like a particle. All of these features are already present in the Copenhagen interpretation in 1927.

Comment: @FlatterMann This experiment is with one neutron in the apparatus at a time. There are also common exp with one photon at a time from the early '50 and there is interferentce pattern after huge number collected. More importantly In a Mach Zehnder with single photons when both arms are open on the second Beamsplitter the photon can go in just one direction with suitable phase shift PS. Change the PS and you get other direction. This is only possible if there is a WF in the both arm with one particle. This is even shown with animation on Wiki.

Comment: @FlatterMann Does not a photon travel as a particle in free space? QFT is based on the quantization of WF, so if QFT says something it is based on WF. By the way QFT says nothing about MZ or DSE. Does it say you get 1/3 of the 'excitation' in one path?

Comment: @FlatterMann What does exactly Bohr said about DSE and MZ? I took some time to understand it. It is merely a legend. He said 1) the arrangement of the exp specifies the results which means that info is coming to the spot where the excitation starts but he denies that a WF is moving backwards 2) No one can tell what is going on in the DSE it is a black box ... so just calculate....   As the experiments were not refined these days he was taken as the last word. For 100 years.  The weak measurements are about to break the spell IMO.

Comment: @Mercury "One photon at a time" language is a complete misunderstanding of both the theory and the experiment. Optical photons don't interact with each other. The problem with low energy optics experiments is simply ontological: it's the belief that photons are objects. They aren't. The only "object" in an interferometer is a quantum field. There are no photons in that field. The photons are the irreversible energy exchanges that are happening at the source and the detectors. In the language of Copenhagen they are what's left AFTER the Born rule is being applied.

Comment: @Mercury On a general note: what any one physicist says about nature is irrelevant. What is relevant is what nature tells us about itself. Einstein's 1905 paper on the photoelectric effect has a huge blunder in it: Einstein identifies the source of the effect as a quantized exchange of energy and then immediately proceeds to assigning corpuscular properties to those quanta. The experiment itself makes no such statement about that energy and energy being represented by corpuscles is the same trivial mistake that happened with the "phlogiston". Even Einstein could not help himself there.

Comment: @FlatterMann I see you are accepting the view that there are no particles but just quantum fields. A particle is excitation of the field. But this excitation is local well below nm range  and its very much localized. Also it is absorbed in a local 'point'. How is QFT explaining a wave looking like a soliton? The QFT excitation is in fact immediate in whole space the Fock states. Making packages don't solve anything as they spread almost immediately.

Comment: @Mercury I have never seen a localized quantum as an experimental physicist. A quantum was always "the size" of my detector. I never had to measure that size. The detector is a manmade object with known dimensions. Troublingly people are willing to assign size to energy, which is a system property. A system in physics is a random and abstract human partition. Nature knows nothing about it. We use systems as a divide and conquer strategy to understand nature. That's it. There are no solitons in free fields, either. Those are emergent matter effects, just like particle tracks. See Mott 1929.

Comment: How large is an atom in your device? Does not the excitation ends meeting it? Or all the atoms in your device are influenced and with what part of its energy hv? Can you find the excitation after it meets the atom? In Bohr the excitation is not real but only probability amplitude. This allows Bohr to collapse it being all over the world in one atom. In QFT it suddenly is thought to be real and that's impossible. I read Mott article before many years. If he had solved the problem it would stay on the cover of all QM/QFT books after 1929. I don't think he avoids collapse of WF.

Comment: Also if you use two time smaller detectors than yours only one will click. The wavelength of infrared light is about km. Does it mean that it is present in km range?